# Hidden Markov Model Gets Stuck Python - Hiiden Markov Model for Eye Movement Detection

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models

I'm working with a Hidden Markov Model (HMM) for classifying eye-tracker data, into saccades or fixations. Saccades are rapid eye movements, and fixations are slow eye movements. 
I have an array with the velocity of the eye movements and I need to classify the points into saccades or fixations. I have the following code:

```
import yahmm

v['velocity'] = calculateVelocity(v)
meanVelocity = v['velocity'].mean()
fixations_ = v.loc[v['velocity'] < meanVelocity]
saccades_ = v.loc[v['velocity'] > meanVelocity]
fixations_time = v['datetime'].loc[v['velocity'] < meanVelocity]
saccades_time = v['datetime'].loc[v['velocity'] > meanVelocity]

#Initialize model
model = Model(name="Saccade-Fixation")
saccade = State(DiscreteDistribution(dict(zip(saccades_time, saccades_))), name="saccades")
fixation = State(DiscreteDistribution(dict(zip(fixations_time, fixations_))), name="fixations")

#Add states to the model.
model.add_state(saccade)
model.add_state(fixation)

#Add the two transitions from the start of of the model to the hidden states.
model.add_transition(model.start, saccade, 0.5)
model.add_transition(model.start, fixation, 0.5)
model.bake()
sequence = model.sample()
```

When I run the code, my computer gets stuck and I can't identify the problem.

Can you please help me?

Comment: At the very least, you need to put some different print statements in several parts of your code and see which is the last one that prints so that you know where it's stuck.

Comment: Debug it using `pdb` or an IDE like `pycharm`?

Comment: I've already done that and when I initialize the model, it gets stuck, so I don't know why it gets stuck in that specific part.

Comment: I debugged it using ipython, but I couldn't identify the problem either :(

Comment: Bearing in mind that I know nothing at all about this, I notice that one of two of the examples in the yahmm wiki use `from yahmm import *` (rather than `import yahmm`). Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Bill Bell, I tried it with import yahmm, but it didn't change a thing. I think that my problem is that there are too many values (there are 11.000 observations for fixations and 6.000 for saccades). Thank you anyway!

Comment: This comment comes a bit too late but if the number of training sequences is the problem, you could have a look at Online-learning for HMMs. It seems to be this approach inplemented with Python. https://github.com/albietz/online_hmm

Comment: Eskapp! Thank you a lot for your help!